# How to retun vector of an generic type from function in Rust. Error E0277 from compiler saying I need to implement Debug. Why?

Tags: rust

Having diffuclty grasping the concept of generics. How can I return a vector from a function with a generic value? I'd like to input text and the output be either a vector of eithers strings or integers. However, the compiler gives me `error[E0277]: <T as FromStr>::Err doesn't implement Debug`. It's telling me that I need to implement the 'Debug'trait? But I don't understand why. How can I simply return a vector of an arbitrary type?

```
use std::str::FromStr;

    fn main() {
    let a: Vec<u32> = text_to_vec("1 2 3 4");
    }


fn text_to_vec<T: FromStr>(text: &str) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut list = Vec::new();

    for word in text.split(" "){
        if let w = word {
            let w = w.parse().unwrap();
            list.push(w);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

I'm expecting to get a vector of u32 integers in this case.

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: Also, what happens when `w.parse()` fails? `unwrap()` is kind of brutal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
error[E0277]: `<T as FromStr>::Err` doesn't implement `Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:12:21
   |
12 |             let w = w.parse().unwrap();
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^ ------ required by a bound introduced by this call
   |                     |
   |                     `<T as FromStr>::Err` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`
   |
   = help: the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `<T as FromStr>::Err`
note: required by a bound in `Result::<T, E>::unwrap`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
   |
7  | fn text_to_vec<T: FromStr>(text: &str) -> Vec<T> where <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug {
   |                                                  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

You should read the full error message since it addresses where the `Debug` requirement comes from and even provides a solution.

Calling [`.unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) requires the error type implements `Debug` since it will display a message with the error if one occurred.

The last part of the error suggests adding a `where` clause to constrain that the error type returned from `.parse()` implements `Debug`.

Another solution would be to ignore or log the error yourself if you don't want to add the constraint. Something using a `match` would work nicely:

```
match w.parse() {
    Ok(w) => list.push(w),
    Err(_) => println!("failed to parse {w}"),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error here is caused by the `unwrap`. `unwrap` creates a panic, which by default attempts to print out the error. This is why it requires that `<T as FromStr>::Err` implements `Debug`. However, your function does not require that.

What I'd recommend is to implement your function using iterators, and returning a `Result` instead. Then you can unwrap elsewhere.

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let a: Vec<u32> = text_to_vec("1 2 3 4").unwrap();
}

fn text_to_vec<T: FromStr>(text: &str) -> Result<Vec<T>, <T as FromStr>::Err> {
    text.split(" ").map(|word| word.parse()).collect()
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to add that bound to your function:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn text_to_vec_unwrap<T>(text: &str) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: FromStr,
    <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug,
{
    text.split(" ").map(|word| word.parse().unwrap()).collect()
}
```